# Don't expand command line mapping (cmap) until pressing enter in vim

Tags: vim

I have

```
cmap w!! %!sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

in my `.vimrc`.

When I type a `w` while writing in the vim command line (after `:`), the cursor stays over the `w` for a few seconds before moving right. This sometimes breaks my train of thought and confuses me for a few seconds.  Is there a way to make the mapping happen when pressing enter after the command so that it doesn't temporarily "eat" the `w` every time I press it?

(Incidentally, this mapping also makes `w!!` expand when I'm typing a search query which isn't annoying in practice (except for the fact that the `w` is similarly delayed) but seems strange.)

Comment: Is this from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7078429 by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried:

```
cabbrev w!! %!sudo tee > /dev/null %
```

which delays the expansion until pressing space or enter, but strangely writes the password prompt *on top of* the expansion of the command, so the command line looks like

```
Password:ee > /dev/null %
```

(and works correctly if you ignore the display error).

Comment: (Anyone know why that happens?)

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behaviour with the [`timeout`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27timeout%27) and [`timeoutlen`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27timeoutlen%27) options. To quote the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#map-typing):

> If the 'timeout' option is on (which is the default) Vim will only
>   wait for one second (or as long as specified with the 'timeoutlen'
>   option). After that it assumes that the character is to be interpreted as such.